# chromatic number of a graph embedded on torus

Tags: graph-theory

if the graph G can be embedded on a torus can we say:

if

$\chi(G)\ge r\Rightarrow K_r\prec G$.

Kr is a minor of G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can say that. First, [Heawood's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heawood_conjecture) (Ringel–Youngs Theorem) states that $\chi(G)\leq 7$. Now, if $\chi(G)\leq 6$, you can apply what is known about [Hadwiger's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_%28graph_theory%29) to get your desired conclusion.

If $\chi(G)=7$, then you can say something a little stronger: $G$ actually contains $K_7$ as a *subgraph*! This is a result of Dirac from 1952, but see "Short proof of a map-colour theorem", Canadian Journal of Mathematics, Vol 9 (1957), 225.

Comment: How do you show the latter statement? I don't see a direct implication from Dirac's article.

Comment: @CuriousGuy I believe for a torus h=3? Is that wrong? It's been a while.